# activate selenium code by bookmark or chrome extension

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, automation

i made a Selenium code with js and i want to active the code by bookmark or extention
is anyone know how can i do it?
i tried to build a regular extension and also with extension cli but unfortunately i cant
my errors:
Service worker registration failed. Status code: 15
Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'executeScript')
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'executeScript')
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot access a chrome:// URL
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

popup code:
// popup.js

```
    document.getElementById('runScript').addEventListener('click', async () => {      
        const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            function: () => {
                // Call the runAutomation function from content.js
                window.runAutomation();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

background file code:

````
    const runScriptButton = document.getElementById('runScript');
    runScriptButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: tab.id },
            function: runAutomationCode
        });
    });
});

// Define the automation function
function main() {
    console.log('Automation code executed');
}```


and my code is in a folder named content.js

```async function main() {
    console.log('start');
;

    try {.... } finally {
        // Quit the browser when done
        await driver.quit();
    }
}
main();
window.main = main```

i cant publish the selenium code because of Data Security
thanks
i trying to run selenium with chrome extention
````

Comment: You're trying to run selenium in a chrome extension? That won't work, you can only run selenium on backend